# Working with Agora.io in Java my Login is rejected by the server. Why am I getting the response code error 2010021?

Tags: agora.io, agora

RTM:ERROR  Error Code 2 - Login is rejected by the server. The response code is 2010021
RTM:ERROR Error Code 2: login failed with args: {"uid":"****"}

Why do I always get an error like that and how do I fix it?

I have adjusted the argument but still get an error like that.